# best way to handle conditional statement

Tags: c#

I have the following condition using in my code but that doesn't look very efficient,is this any better way to handle ?

```
if (ic = filename.Contains(".wmv"))
{
    if (bitnumber > 400)
    {
        path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "media" + "/" + "lib" + "/" + programName + "/" + date + "/";
        UploadCondition(path, filename);
        //return path;
    }
}

if (ic = filename.Contains(".wmv"))
{
    if (bitnumber < 400)
    {
        path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
        UploadCondition(path, filename);
        //return path;
    }
}

if (ic = filename.Contains(".m4v"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}

if (ic = filename.Contains(".mp4"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
if (ic = filename.Contains(".flv"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
if (ic = filename.Contains(".mpg"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
if (ic = filename.Contains(".aac"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "audio" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
if (ic = filename.Contains(".mp3"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "audio" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
```

Comment: Just `filename.Contains` should also evaluate, whatz with `ic` ?Maybe you could extract the extension and make this into a `switch`

Comment: Something wrong here, why you need this ic?

Comment: Have a look at jgauffin's response.  There's a lot of code you have that's repeated.  Whenever you see that, look at how you can extract methods out.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you guys to provide so much idea.

Comment: @IamStalker ,i suppose to use it like if(filename.Contains(".m4v")),i was practicing with boolean value.i will change in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it up in other classes like:

```
public class AudioFileValidator
{
    private List<string> _extensions = new List<string>{".aac", ".mp3"};
    public bool IsValid(string filename)
    {
        if (!_extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filename))
            return false;

        //validate bitrate etc
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var audioValidator = new AudioFileValidator();
if (audioValidator.IsValid(filename)) 
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "audio" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}

var videoValidator = new VideoFileValidator();
if (videoValidator.IsValid(filename)) 
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
```

By doing so you'll get classes with a single responsibility which can be reused in other places and which are easy to unit test.

---

You could even take it further and introduce a new interface called `IMediaFileValidator` which all validators implement. and do something like:

```
foreach (var validator in validators)
{ 
    if (validator.IsValid(filename))
    {
        // use info from the validator to build the path
        var mediaName = validator.MediaName; 
        path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + mediaName + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
        UploadCondition(path, filename);
        break;
    }
}
```

Which would also make your code adhere to Open/Closed principle.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a lot of refactoring. Here are couple of ideas to get you started:

- Use String.Format and passed in only value that changed to save you all the repeating the text
- Build a dictionary of Extension/Ext-Combination key and set the value to the the destination path. You will then only require one lookup than big nesting if - else statements
- Use Path.GetExtension rather than Contains to be more accurate

Eg.

```
  string formatStringNews = "ftp://{0}/news/{1}/";
  string formatStringMedia = "ftp://{0}/media/{1}/";
  dictionary["wmv"] = formatStringMedia;
  dictionary["mp3"] = formatStringNews;
  ....
  string key = Path.GetExtension(filename);
  path = string.Format(dictionary[key], serverName, programName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is a nice short solution to your problem and I believe it handles all of the cases your if statements are handling.

```
String[] videoExtensions = { "wmv", "m4v", "mp4", "flv" };
String[] audioExtensions = { "aac", "mp3" };

String ext = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
String path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/";

if (-1 != Array.IndexOf(videoExtensions, ext)) {
  if ("wmv".equals(ext) && bitnumber > 400)
    path += "media/lib/" + programName + "/" + date + "/";
  else 
    path += "mpegmedia/news/" + programName + "/video/podcast/";
}
else if (-1 != Array.IndexOf(audioExtensions, ext)) {
  path += "mpegmedia/news/" + programName + "/audio/podcast/";
}​​​​​​​​​​​
else {
  // handle unknown extension types as desired
}

UploadCondition(path, filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `switch` statement and `System.IO.Path.GetExtension`.

```
select (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename))
{
    case ".wmv":
        if (bitnumber > 400)
        {
            path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "media" + "/" + "lib" + "/" + programName + "/" + date + "/";
            UploadCondition(path, filename);
            //return path;
        }
        else
        {
            path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
            UploadCondition(path, filename);
            //return path;
        }
        break;

        case ".m4v":
        case ".mp4":
        case ".flv":
        case ".mpg":
        case ".mp3":
        default:
            path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
            UploadCondition(path, filename);
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing you'll want variations for the last block, but this should be easy enough to modify.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you could convert it into an if/elseif statement:

```
if (ic....)
{
    ...
} else if (ic...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Given all of the problems in the code presented, this is probably the least influential one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, at a time your `filename` will be either be .m4v, .flv,.mp4 etc...so here goes the code..

```
    if (ic = filename.Contains(".wmv"))
{
    if (bitnumber > 400)
    {
        path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "media" + "/" + "lib" + "/" + programName + "/" + date + "/";
        UploadCondition(path, filename);
        //return path;
    }

        else
        {
        path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
        UploadCondition(path, filename);
        //return path;
    }
}

    else if (ic = filename.Contains(".m4v"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}

else if (ic = filename.Contains(".mp4"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
else if (ic = filename.Contains(".flv"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
else if (ic = filename.Contains(".mpg"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "video" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
else if (ic = filename.Contains(".aac"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "audio" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
else if (ic = filename.Contains(".mp3"))
{
    path = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + "mpegmedia" + "/" + "news" + "/" + programName + "/" + "audio" + "/" + "podcast" + "/";
    UploadCondition(path, filename);
}
    else
    {
        //No Match found
    }
```

and the best approach would be to use `Switch(fileExtn)`

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps make it a bit simpler like

```
if (filename.Contains(".wmv"))
    // path =  set the path as you require
```

and after all the ifs end call your method

```
UploadCondition(path, filename);
```

Better would be to extract the extension `.wmv, .m4v` from filename and make this into a switch whereby you set the path.